# Add namespace definitions on document level

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces, docx4j

I'm dynamically generating a DOCX document with multiple paragraphs. Since docx4j was complaining that the namespace definitions were missing, I added them in my `<w:p />` element. It seems like this works fine.

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wpMLPackage = getWordTemplate(FOOBAR);
MainDocumentPart mdp = wpMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();

for (i = 0; i < LIMIT; ++i) {
    String paragraphXml = "<w:p xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" xmlns:v=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml\" w:rsidR=\"00085705\" xmlns:mc=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006\" xmlns:wp14=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing\" xmlns:a=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main\" xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:wp=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing\" xmlns:wps=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape\" w:rsidRDefault=\"0088320D\">...</w:p>";

    mdp.addParagraph(paragraphXml);
}
```

However, since I'm repeating the paragraph in a loop, the namespace definitions will be added more than once. It would make more sense to insert them only once on a higher level. But I don't know how to do that.

How can I add the `xmlns:*` arguments on a higher level in the XML structure? Are there any methods in `MainDocumentPart` or `WordprocessingMLPackage` that I can use? Word adds the namespace definitions to `<w:document />`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should "just work".  That is, without changing your code, JAXB will put the namespace declarations at the document level.

Comment: I checked the DOCX file, you are right. Except for ``xmlns:wps`` which is repeated for each paragraph. So this is how it is supposed to be done, I do not need to add the namespaces to the document root explicitly?